# $\int_{\varphi } {f}'/f = 0$ if $f(z)$ has no non positiv real values

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, complex-integration, holomorph

$\varphi$ is closed curve in $\mathbb{C}$, $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomoprh on a doman $G$ with image of $\varphi$ subset of G. If $(f(z): z\in \varphi^{*})$ ($\varphi^{*}$ image of $\varphi$) has NO non-positiv real Points then:
$$\int_{\varphi } {f}'/f = 0$$

How to show this part? I know this is complex logarithm but I´m not sure how to use the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log z$ has a holomorphic branch on the slit plane with the non-negative
reals removed. If we call this branch $l(z)$ then
$$\frac d{dz}l(f(z))=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$
and the integral becomes
$$\int_{\varphi}\frac d{dz}l(f(z))\,dz=0$$
as we are integrating a derivative over a closed contour.